# Linux Mint Vhost, Yii2 - using subdomain as ID

Tags: apache, ubuntu, yii2, apache2, vhosts

I am trying to setup vhost to have dynamic subdomains, so I can use them as ID. I am kinda half way there - the site is working, but when Idry subdomain, I get **Server not found** error. 
This is my conf file so far:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.1.1:80>  

    DocumentRoot /var/www/c2c/Care2Shine/www

    ServerAlias *.*.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/c2c/www
    UseCanonicalName Off

    <Directory /var/www/c2c/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my /etc/hosts file have this:

```
127.0.1.1   c2s.dev
127.0.1.1   *.c2s.dev
```

How can I setup vhost in order to capture subdomain and use it as ID?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do dynamic subdomains without DNS server.
For workaround on localhost, you should create some subdomains in /etc/hosts for testing.

```
127.0.1.1   c2s.dev
127.0.1.1   subdomain1.c2s.dev
127.0.1.1   subdomain2.c2s.dev
```

So after deploying on server, everything will work.